# Simple way to display java.util.logging xml files?

Tags: java, xml, logging, java.util.logging

This module is great for logging... it produces XML files like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
-<log>
-<record>
<date>2016-07-08T19:24:29</date>
<millis>1468002269560</millis>
<sequence>0</sequence>
<logger>java.lang.Class</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>root.LoggingTest2</class>
<method>main</method>
<thread>1</thread>
<message># logging this message...</message>
</record>
</log>
```

... is there a simple freeware app to let me display this XML stuff in a convenient, human-readable form?  Or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/282021/free-tool-for-graphical-representations-of-xml-files

Comment: [XSLT - Transformation](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp)

Comment: @VinceWest thanks... useful but not practical: you would have to expand zillions of nodes manually - but in the real world you want to scan through log files fast, noting things like red font for error logs, noting times, noting threads, etc.  without doing any hard slog

Comment: @jmehrens yes... good stuff.  One layer of abstraction too far, perhaps, in the sense that I now have to learn this XSLT technology/language.  I was hoping that java.logging XML output would be such a common thing it would available "off the shelf".  Sigh.  Never that simple.  Wonder what others do?  Maybe java.logging's XML format is not used much, and instead people "roll their own" output format (to HTML typically)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very well thought-out approach to java.util.logging, which includes a solution to viewing the XML files, can be found here: http://www.forward.com.au/javaProgramming/javaGuiTips/javaLogging.html

... however, reading around the subject, the pros make a good case for not using java.util.logging (JUL), but instead something like SLF4J and Logback...